# Elasticsearch - Analyser creating the right tokens but query is not matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make Elasticsearch ignore hyphens.  I don't want it to split either side of the hyphen into seperate words. It seems simple but I'm banging my head on the wall.

I want the string "Roland JD-Xi" to produce the following terms:
[ roland jd-xi, roland, jd-xi, jdxi, roland jdxi ]

I haven't been able to achieve this easily.  Most people will just type 'jdxi' so my initial thought would be to just remove the hyphen.  So I'm using the following definition

```
  name: {
"type": "string",
"analyzer": "language",
"include_in_all": true,
"boost": 5,
"fields": {
    "my_standard": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "my_standard"
    },
    "my_prefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "my_text_prefix",
        "search_analyzer": "my_standard"
    },
    "my_suffix": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "my_text_suffix",
        "search_analyzer": "my_standard"
    }
}
```

}

And the relevant analyser and filters are defined as

```
{
"number_of_replicas": 0,
"number_of_shards": 1,
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "std": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "char_filter": "html_strip",
            "filter": ["standard", "elision", "asciifolding", "lowercase", "stop", "length", "strip_hyphens"]
        ...
        "my_text_prefix": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "char_filter": "my_filter",
            "filter": ["standard", "elision", "asciifolding", "lowercase", "stop", "edge_ngram_front"]
        },
        "my_text_suffix": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "char_filter": "my_filter",
            "filter": ["standard", "elision", "asciifolding", "lowercase", "stop", "edge_ngram_back"]
        },
        "my_standard": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "char_filter": "my_filter",
            "filter": ["standard", "elision", "asciifolding", "lowercase"]
        }
    },
    "char_filter": {
        "my_filter": {
            "type": "mapping",
            "mappings": ["- => ", ". => "]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "edge_ngram_front": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 20,
            "side": "front"
        },
        "edge_ngram_back": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 20,
            "side": "back"
        },
        "strip_spaces": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\\s",
            "replacement": ""
        },
        "strip_dots": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\\.",
            "replacement": ""
        },
        "strip_hyphens": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "-",
            "replacement": ""
        },
        "stop": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": "_none_"
        },
        "length": {
            "type": "length",
            "min": 1
        }
    }
}
```

I've been able to test (i.e. _analyze) this and the string "Roland JD-Xi" is tokenised as 
[ roland, jdxi ]

It not exactly what I want but close enough as it should match 'jdxi'.

But thats my problem.  If I do a simple "index/_search?q=jdxi" it doesn't bring back the document.  However if I do a "index/_search?q=roland+jdxi" it does bring back the document.

So at least I know the hyphens are being removed but if the tokens "roland" and "jdxi" are being created how come "index/_search?q=jdxi" doesn't match the document?

1. Is my problem with the index process or the query process?
2. How do I fix it?
3. Can anyone explain how to achieve the desired tokens
   [ roland jd-xi, roland, jd-xi, jdxi, roland jdxi ]

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I've reproduced your case on ES 6 and searching for `index/_search?q=jdxi` returns the document.

The issue could be that when searching for `index/_search?q=jdxi` without specifying a field, it will basically search in `_all` which contains whatever was in the `name` field (basically the same as `index/_search?q=name:jdxi`). Since that field was not analyzed using your `my_standard` analyzer, you don't get any results.

What you should do instead is searching using the `my_standard` sub-field, i.e. `index/_search?q=name.my_standard:jdxi` and pretty sure you'll get the document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Val and yes your query does retrieve the right document.  But this is all for an eCommerce search and so although I can see that specifying the my_standard sub-field will match the right thing I need a generic search (i.e. a simple query entered by a standard website user) to bring this document back.  So I need a search in "_all" to ignore hyphens.  Should I be modifying the index process or the query process to achieve this behaviour.  I'm using Version
5.6.8.

Comment: You can prefix `name.my_standard:` to whatever the user inputs into the search fields and build your query that way. Feasible?

Comment: Possibly.  I am investigating now.  But is there not a way "Roland JD-Xi"  can be split into "roland", "jdxi" and "roland jdxi" and then shoved into a pot to work against a fuzzy match query?

Comment: If you want to go the fuzzy match way, your next problem will be that `jaxi` will also match and that's probably not what you want. Fuzzy should always come as a last resort when you have exhausted all other possibilities or under certain very specific circumstances.

Comment: Okay, good point. I'm using https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica so I guess I just need to work out how to build the correct query.

Comment: Sure let us know how it goes.